# Doing conditional replacement using c++ macro?

Tags: c++, c

For a `struct point{float x,y,z;},` i want to define many functions, in each function, i do the same thing to `x`, `y` and `z`. For example, `float size = 1 * x*y*z`, `float edge = 0+x+y+z`...
So I'm wondering that, i could write a macro, or something, like
`#define forxyz(codes) ???????`
that when i write
`forxyz(res=res+d;)`
it calls `res=res+x; res=res+y;res=res+z;`

Urrr, lemme make it more clear. I have about 20 functions, each one is called for only one time, so I don't want to attach them to the struct. Moreover, it's not as simple as '+'. for example, i might have

```
x_in_middle(point a, point b, point c, float d){
    if(b.x<a.x && a.x<c.x){
        if(d>0) return a.x;
        if(d<0) return a.x*a.x;
        if(d==0) return 0;
    }
}
```

and I'm finding a way to not to write

```
if(b.x<a.x && a.x<c.x){
        if(d>0) return a.x;
        if(d<0) return a.x*a.x;
        if(d=0) return 0;
    }
```

three times!

In this case `res=res+d` is pretty simple, but in my case it might be several lines of codes...and sometime i would want to call `set_x, set_y, set_z` functions...

So far, the best idea i could have is to make `res=res+d` another macro, namely
`#define add(d) res=res+d`
and then

```
add(x);
add(y);
add(z);
```

But this would obviously create too much macros, and i think it's not elegant...

Comment: Why not just a class that overloads all those operators? (There are also libraries like glm that provide such classes)

Comment: IMHO, there are two choices:  add functionality to your `point` structure for adding `point` structures (this could also be performed by overloading operators).  Another choice, is to create free-standing functions that take `point` variables as parameters.

Comment: There's no reason to use this approach in C++. That's a C thing.

Comment: You're going to wind up with "too much" of something, whether that's macros or helper functions. I recommend the helper functions. Long macros and chains of macros become hard to debug.

Comment: @churill what do you mean by operators? I think i still can't avoid repeat the same code three times for x, y and z

Comment: `res=res+x; res=res+y;res=res+z;` why not `res += x + y + z;`?

Comment: @Bobi.Liu Yes, but you would have to write everything onces for `x, y, z` but then you can use the overloaded operators, which will be shorter than to repeat a macro several times.

Comment: `if(d=0)` is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer that answers the macro part and I would advise to provide operators overloads if possible and not to use macros in C++.

So first create your own small overloaded foreach macro that will apply a function on each argument:

```
#define M_FOREACH_1(func,_1) \
        func(_1)
#define M_FOREACH_2(func,_1,_2) \
        M_FOREACH_1(func,_1)func(_2)
#define M_FOREACH_3(func,_1,_2,_3) \
        M_FOREACH_2(func,_1,_2)func(_3)
/// etc.
#define M_FOREACH_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) \
        M_FOREACH_##N
#define M_FOREACH(func, ...) \
        M_FOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(func, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Then let's abstract it for some argument braced list that needs to be escaped, for verbosity:

```
#define M_FOREACHLIST_ESCAPE(...)  \
        __VA_ARGS__
#define M_FOREACHLIST_IN(func, ...) \
        M_FOREACH(func, __VA_ARGS__)
#define M_FOREACHLIST(func, list) \
        M_FOREACHLIST_IN(func, M_FOREACHLIST_ESCAPE list)
// now we can
// M_FOREACHLIST(some_macro, (x, y, z))
```

After that it's typicall to define a function for expansion, apply it foreach some arguments list:

```
#define list() (x, y, z)

#define add(arg)  res = res + arg;
M_FOREACHLIST(add, list())
// generates res = res + x;res = res + y;res = res + z;
#undef add

#define sub(arg)  res = res - arg;
M_FOREACHLIST(sub, list())
// generates res = res - x;res = res - y;res = res - z;
#undef sub

// etc.
```

> and I'm finding a way to not to write ... three times!

Pass member pointer to the function...

```
float generic_in_middle(point a, point b, point c, float d, float point::* mp){
    if (b.*mp < a.*mp && a.*mp < c.*mp){
        if (d > 0) return a.*mp;
        if (d < 0) return a.*mp * a.*mp;
        if (d == 0) return 0;
    }
    // TODO: add code here so that function returns something
}
float x_in_middle(point a, point b, point c, float d) {
    return generic_in_middle(a, b, c, d, &point::x); 
}
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to write a freestanding function that takes `point`s as parameters:

```
point add(const point& a, const point& b)
{
  point c;
  c.x = a.x + b.x;
  c.y = a.y + b.y;
  c.z = a.z + b.z;
  return c;
}
```

You would use this like:

```
point a, b, c;
//...
c = add(a, b);
```

You could also overload `operator +`:

```
point operator+(const point& a, const point& b)
{
  point c;
  c.x = a.x + b.x;
  c.y = a.y + b.y;
  c.z = a.z + b.z;
  return c;
}
```

Your usage may look like this:

```
point a, b, c;
//...
c = a + b;
```

Comment: I call this kind of "add" exactly one time, so i don't think this is a good idea

Comment: A better solution is to implement `operator +=` and `operator+` in the `struct`.  I posted this simple solution to get the OP on their way faster.

Comment: @Bobi.Liu How is this "add once" not a good idea?  You can use the function many times:  `point d = (a + b) + c;`

Answer (score 1):

#### Delegate axis-specific public API functions to a common helper function or operator

As the three data members are all of the same type, and you want to implement re-usable, say, arithmetic operations applied on a single one of them, you could wrap the common arithmetic functionality in a private helper, and delegate publically expose axis-specific functions to the helper.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {   
    Point(float x, float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
    
    float addX(const float a) const { return add(x_, a); }
    float addY(const float a) const { return add(y_, a); }
    float addZ(const float a) const { return add(z_, a); }
    
private:
    static float add(const float lhs, const float rhs) { 
        // Long complex arithmetic code.
        return lhs + rhs; 
    }

    float x_;
    float y_;
    float z_;
};

int main() {
    const Point p{1., 2., 3.};
    std::cout << p.addY(0.5); // 2.5
    
    return 0;
}
```

You *could* likewise resort to implementing the helper as a member function template with a a single pointer to member function non-type template parameter, and delegate calls to this function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {   
    Point(float x, float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
    
    float addX(const float a) const { return add<&Point::x_>(a); }
    float addY(const float a) const { return add<&Point::y_>(a); }
    float addZ(const float a) const { return add<&Point::z_>(a); }
    
private:
    template <float Point::* lhs>
    float add(const float rhs) const { 
        // Long complex arithmetic code
        // on lhs.
        return rhs + (this->*lhs); 
    }

    float x_;
    float y_;
    float z_;
};

int main() {
    const Point p{1., 2., 3.};
    std::cout << p.addY(0.5); // 2.5
    
    return 0;
}
```

#### (C++20) Looping over a known number of public members: structured bindings in a range-based for loop initialization statement

Another alternative, as a simple POD-type such as a *point* data type is likely to have data members with public access modifiers, as of C++20 we may combine [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) with [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) initialization statements (the latter is a C++20 feature):

> **Grammar**
>
> for ( *init-statement(optional)* *range-declaration* : *range-expression* ) ...

Specifically, using structured bindings as the *init-statement* in a range-based for loop:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {   
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

float add(const float lhs, const float rhs) {
    // Long complex arithmetic code.
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main() {
    const Point p{1., 2., 3.};

    // For all members, do ...
    for (auto [x, y, z] = p; auto e : {x, y, z}) {
        std::cout << add(0.5, e) << " ";
    } // 1.5 2.5 3.5
    
    return 0;
}
```