# Type-qualification Macro Helper

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

How do I make a helper macro for tedious repetition when qualifying a type?

Look at `std::is_function` for example -- how would I make macros to help save me time writing all those possible cases? (Obviously, this isn't just a C++ issue, but it's much more manageable in C)

Here's what I was thinking, but it's hurting my brain (and doesn't work):

```
#define empty_macro

#define finally_apply( macro, ... ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__ )

#define apply_cv( macro, ... ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, empty_macro ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, const ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, volatile ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, const volatile )


#define apply_pointer( macro, ... ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, empty_macro ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, * )

// c++ only
#define apply_noexcept( macro, ... ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, empty_macro ) \
    macro( __VA_ARGS__, noexcept )
```

I'm not interested in using an external library like Boost. I'd like to know how to do it myself.

[See "Possible implementation" for more information.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function)

Comment: @jwdonahue The C++ solution is the same as the C solution as the standards between the two are identical with regard to macros. They are also unchanged by time (ignoring the new C++20 macro features). My question feels fine to include both.

Comment: Please [edit] to information to the question, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: Please show [mre] of examples of how you would like to use the macros and elaborate on "it doesn't work". Please show the pre-processed version of the example code, to help debugging what went wrong.

Comment: Do you insist on having the varargs up front? I usually like to put the "reliable" parameters up front.

Comment: I don't get the point of `empty_macro`. Is it defined somewhere?

Comment: @RubberBee `#define empty_macro` is empty to just make the argument no be substituted with anything.

Comment: Please [edit] to add information to the question itself, instead of hiding it down here among the comments.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of how you want to use the macros.

Comment: [See "Possible implementation".](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function)

Comment: That could be seen as an example of what you want to avoid or as an example of what you want your macros to expand to. Please demonstrate how you would like to use the macros you are trying to implement. While I respect your goal to save on typing effort, please do spend some effort on providing helpful information in your question. Add an explanation of "doesn't work". Add the preprocessed version of the example of how you want to use the macros, based on the "doesn't work attempt". Please.

Comment: It **IS** and example of *both*. I'd like to make a utility like `apply_cv( apply_ref( apply_noexcept( macro_for_std_is_function_struct ) ) )`

Comment: Just few days ago I have written [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519709/doing-conditional-replacement-using-c-macro/62520236#62520236) that applies a list on a macro

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write the lists of "combinations of cv-qualifiers", "noexcept-ness", etc, in an uniform manner.

Here's an easier approach. These macros generate specializations of `std::is_function`:

```
#define FUNC(a, b) \
    struct is_function<Ret(Args... a) b> : std::true_type {};
    
#define FUNCLIST_D(c, v, ref, ne) \
    FUNC(   , c v ref ne) \
    FUNC(..., c v ref ne)
    
#define FUNCLIST_C(v, ref, ne) \
    FUNCLIST_D(     , v, ref, ne) \
    FUNCLIST_D(const, v, ref, ne)
    
#define FUNCLIST_B(ref, ne) \
    FUNCLIST_C(        , ref, ne) \
    FUNCLIST_C(volatile, ref, ne)
    
#define FUNCLIST_A(ne) \
    FUNCLIST_B(  , ne) \
    FUNCLIST_B(& , ne) \
    FUNCLIST_B(&&, ne)
    
#define FUNCLIST \
    FUNCLIST_A(        ) \
    FUNCLIST_A(noexcept)

FUNCLIST
```

I hope I didn't forget anything. This expands to:

```
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......)> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile &> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile &&> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) & noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) & noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile &noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) && noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) && noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) volatile &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) const volatile &&noexcept> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to write these macros every time I'd like to do something

Comment: @superdeveloper Yes, those macros are tailored to a specific case (generating `is_function`), but how often do you need to generate code like that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you asked for it.

Let's first start with an FOREACH macro that allows a custom escaped separator and escapes it's arguments overloaded for some big number of arguments. By "escaped" I mean in braces. With such macro `M_FOREACHQS(macro, (separator), ((1), (2), (3)))` generates `macro(1)separator macro(2)separator macro(3)` (I hope):

```
#define M_ESCAPE(...)  __VA_ARGS__

#define M_FOREACHQS_1(F,S,_1)  F(M_ESCAPE _1)
// seq 2 64 | while read l; do echo "#define M_FOREACHQS_$l(F,S,$(seq -f _%.0f $l | paste -sd ,)) \\"; echo $'\t'"M_FOREACHQS_$((l-1))(F,S,$(seq -f _%.0f $((l-1)) | paste -sd ,))M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _$l)"; done
// TODO: Remove additional space before function, I guess with `##` or with empty `M_ESCAPE()`
#define M_FOREACHQS_2(F,S,_1,_2) \
    M_FOREACHQS_1(F,S,_1)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _2)
#define M_FOREACHQS_3(F,S,_1,_2,_3) \
    M_FOREACHQS_2(F,S,_1,_2)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _3)
#define M_FOREACHQS_4(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4) \
    M_FOREACHQS_3(F,S,_1,_2,_3)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _4)
#define M_FOREACHQS_5(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5) \
    M_FOREACHQS_4(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _5)
#define M_FOREACHQS_6(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6) \
    M_FOREACHQS_5(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _6)
#define M_FOREACHQS_7(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7) \
    M_FOREACHQS_6(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _7)
#define M_FOREACHQS_8(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8) \
    M_FOREACHQS_7(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _8)
#define M_FOREACHQS_9(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9) \
    M_FOREACHQS_8(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _9)
#define M_FOREACHQS_10(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10) \
    M_FOREACHQS_9(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _10)
#define M_FOREACHQS_11(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11) \
    M_FOREACHQS_10(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _11)
#define M_FOREACHQS_12(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12) \
    M_FOREACHQS_11(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _12)
#define M_FOREACHQS_13(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13) \
    M_FOREACHQS_12(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _13)
#define M_FOREACHQS_14(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14) \
    M_FOREACHQS_13(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _14)
#define M_FOREACHQS_15(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15) \
    M_FOREACHQS_14(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _15)
#define M_FOREACHQS_16(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16) \
    M_FOREACHQS_15(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _16)
#define M_FOREACHQS_17(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17) \
    M_FOREACHQS_16(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _17)
#define M_FOREACHQS_18(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18) \
    M_FOREACHQS_17(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _18)
#define M_FOREACHQS_19(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19) \
    M_FOREACHQS_18(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _19)
#define M_FOREACHQS_20(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20) \
    M_FOREACHQS_19(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _20)
#define M_FOREACHQS_21(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21) \
    M_FOREACHQS_20(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _21)
#define M_FOREACHQS_22(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22) \
    M_FOREACHQS_21(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _22)
#define M_FOREACHQS_23(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23) \
    M_FOREACHQS_22(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _23)
#define M_FOREACHQS_24(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24) \
    M_FOREACHQS_23(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _24)
#define M_FOREACHQS_25(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25) \
    M_FOREACHQS_24(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _25)
#define M_FOREACHQS_26(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26) \
    M_FOREACHQS_25(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _26)
#define M_FOREACHQS_27(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27) \
    M_FOREACHQS_26(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _27)
#define M_FOREACHQS_28(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28) \
    M_FOREACHQS_27(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _28)
#define M_FOREACHQS_29(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29) \
    M_FOREACHQS_28(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _29)
#define M_FOREACHQS_30(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30) \
    M_FOREACHQS_29(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _30)
#define M_FOREACHQS_31(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31) \
    M_FOREACHQS_30(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _31)
#define M_FOREACHQS_32(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32) \
    M_FOREACHQS_31(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _32)
#define M_FOREACHQS_33(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33) \
    M_FOREACHQS_32(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _33)
#define M_FOREACHQS_34(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34) \
    M_FOREACHQS_33(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _34)
#define M_FOREACHQS_35(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35) \
    M_FOREACHQS_34(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _35)
#define M_FOREACHQS_36(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36) \
    M_FOREACHQS_35(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _36)
#define M_FOREACHQS_37(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37) \
    M_FOREACHQS_36(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _37)
#define M_FOREACHQS_38(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38) \
    M_FOREACHQS_37(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _38)
#define M_FOREACHQS_39(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39) \
    M_FOREACHQS_38(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _39)
#define M_FOREACHQS_40(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40) \
    M_FOREACHQS_39(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _40)
#define M_FOREACHQS_41(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41) \
    M_FOREACHQS_40(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _41)
#define M_FOREACHQS_42(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42) \
    M_FOREACHQS_41(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _42)
#define M_FOREACHQS_43(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43) \
    M_FOREACHQS_42(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _43)
#define M_FOREACHQS_44(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44) \
    M_FOREACHQS_43(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _44)
#define M_FOREACHQS_45(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45) \
    M_FOREACHQS_44(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _45)
#define M_FOREACHQS_46(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46) \
    M_FOREACHQS_45(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _46)
#define M_FOREACHQS_47(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47) \
    M_FOREACHQS_46(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _47)
#define M_FOREACHQS_48(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48) \
    M_FOREACHQS_47(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _48)
#define M_FOREACHQS_49(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49) \
    M_FOREACHQS_48(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _49)
#define M_FOREACHQS_50(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50) \
    M_FOREACHQS_49(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _50)
#define M_FOREACHQS_51(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51) \
    M_FOREACHQS_50(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _51)
#define M_FOREACHQS_52(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52) \
    M_FOREACHQS_51(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _52)
#define M_FOREACHQS_53(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53) \
    M_FOREACHQS_52(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _53)
#define M_FOREACHQS_54(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54) \
    M_FOREACHQS_53(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _54)
#define M_FOREACHQS_55(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55) \
    M_FOREACHQS_54(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _55)
#define M_FOREACHQS_56(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56) \
    M_FOREACHQS_55(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _56)
#define M_FOREACHQS_57(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57) \
    M_FOREACHQS_56(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _57)
#define M_FOREACHQS_58(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58) \
    M_FOREACHQS_57(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _58)
#define M_FOREACHQS_59(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59) \
    M_FOREACHQS_58(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _59)
#define M_FOREACHQS_60(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60) \
    M_FOREACHQS_59(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _60)
#define M_FOREACHQS_61(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61) \
    M_FOREACHQS_60(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _61)
#define M_FOREACHQS_62(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62) \
    M_FOREACHQS_61(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _62)
#define M_FOREACHQS_63(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63) \
    M_FOREACHQS_62(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _63)
#define M_FOREACHQS_64(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64) \
    M_FOREACHQS_63(F,S,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63)M_ESCAPE S F(M_ESCAPE _64)
// seq 64 | tac | paste -sd ,
#define M_FOREACHQS_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,N,...) \
        M_FOREACHQS_##N
// seq 64 | tac | paste -sd ,
#define M_FOREACHQS(F, S, ...) \
        M_FOREACHQS_N(__VA_ARGS__,64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(F, S, __VA_ARGS__)
```

We will generate function definitions in some macro that takes two arguments - the variadic `...` part of the function parameter list and the type:

```
// needs another expansion wave, cause it's applied on `(..., const)`.
#define M_DEFINE_IS_FUNCTION(...) \
        M_DEFINE_IS_FUNCTION_IN(__VA_ARGS__)

#define M_DEFINE_IS_FUNCTION_IN(VAR, TYPE) \
template<class Ret, class... Args> \
struct is_function<Ret(Args... VAR) TYPE> : true_type {};
```

Some basic definition to get us started:

```
// Meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeep
struct true_type { static constexpr bool value = true; };
struct false_type { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<class> struct is_function : false_type { };
```

Then we have to generate each permutations of possible combinations (I never know how it's called) of qualifiers, noexcept, && or & or nothing and variadic or not arguments list. Having two lists `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` I want to have a list `(a c, a d, b c, b d)` and do that 4 times. I do that with a set of overloaded macros that are applied on each other lists, and the result is once again applied on the definition macro above:

```
// Honestly, this could be generalized too...
#define M_CONST_APPLY(...) \
    (__VA_ARGS__), \
    (__VA_ARGS__ const)
#define M_VOLATILE_APPLY(...) \
    (__VA_ARGS__ ), \
    (__VA_ARGS__ volatile)
#define M_REFS_APPLY(...)  \
    (__VA_ARGS__ ), \
    (__VA_ARGS__ &), \
    (__VA_ARGS__ &&)
#define M_NOEXCEPT_APPLY(...)  \
    (__VA_ARGS__), \
    (__VA_ARGS__ noexcept)

M_FOREACHQS(M_DEFINE_IS_FUNCTION, (),
    M_FOREACHQS(M_NOEXCEPT_APPLY, (,),
        M_FOREACHQS(M_REFS_APPLY, (,),
            M_FOREACHQS(M_VOLATILE_APPLY, (,),
                M_FOREACHQS(M_CONST_APPLY, (,),
                    // Arguments list - empty or ... variadic function
                    // We do two arguments here
                    (, ),
                    (..., )
                 )
            )
        )
    )
)

int main() {
    return is_function<int()>::value;
}
```

And [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/Jd7FL3). To be honest, code is easier to maintain, manage and understand when you just type all the possible combinations.